# Copy Paste Across Worksheets (VBA)

Tags: vba

I don't know why, I just can't get this to work. I've simplified it right down to just three lines - but it's causing me problems still.

Basically I want to open a workbook and copy some data from it into a master workbook.

I have:

```
Sub copypaste()

Workbooks.Open("...Test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

I've seen runtime error 438 (object does not support this property method), I can get paste that but just hit 1004 application defined error or object defined error.

I honestly have no idea where I'm going wrong on this simple task!

Thank you in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Try closing the workbook after pasting the data.
As an example you can use something like:

```
Sub copypaste()

    Dim WBopen As Workbook, Wb As Workbook

    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set WBopen = Workbooks.Open("...Test.xlsx")

    WBopen.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Copy
    Wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    WBopen.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are closing the `Workbook` before the data is pasted it fails.

It is also preferred to not use `.Copy` and `.Paste` when it can be avoided.

See example below for a direct setting of the `Values`:

```
Sub copypaste()

    Dim wbMaster As Workbook, wbData As Workbook

    Set wbMaster = Workbooks("Master.xlsm")
    Set wbData = Workbooks.Open("Data.xlsx")

    wbMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = wbData.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    wbData.Close False

End Sub
```